# react, updating useState array only works after the 2nd submit

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onchange

I write a function in react, that should read a string
cut out addresses from the string an give the data back to the backend.
I can already fill an empty useState array with "leads", however this only works
after the 2nd submit. Where could be the problem here?

I use setLeads(leads => [...leads,newLead]) within the loop that creates these
address objects. If I create another array within the loop and add the whole
array of objects outside the loop I have the same result, I always need 2 submits.

It should only be used useState() but not useEffect() here.

```
 import {Fragment, useState} from "react";
 import Layout from "./pages/Layout";

 function App() {

  const [values,setValues] = useState({

    string: 'Select item 469 James Bond James Bond jamesbond@outlook.com api True Select item 
    470 Freddy Mercury Freddy Mercury freddymercury@gmail.com api True Select item 471 Brian 
     May Brian May brianmay@astrarecords.co.uk api True',

    error: false,
    success: false
})

const [leads,setLeads] = useState([
    {

        firstname: "",
        lastname: "",
        email: ""

    }
]);

const {string, error, success} = values


const clickSubmit = (e) => {

   e.preventDefault()
   parseString();

   //this console log shows that the array leads is only filled after the 2nd submit
   console.log(leads);
  
}


const handleChange = name => e => {

  setValues({...values, [name]:e.target.value})
}

const parseString = () => {

const chunks = string.split("Select item ");


 for(let i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {

     let ck = chunks[i].split(" "); 

     let newLead = {

        firstname: ck[1],
        lastname: ck[2],
        email: ck[5]
     }

   setLeads(leads => [...leads,newLead])  
   
 }

 }

function formInput() {
   return (

    <Fragment>

    <h3>Please enter the text here:</h3>

    <form onSubmit={clickSubmit}>


      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Textarea</label>
        <textarea onChange={handleChange('string')} className="form-control" 
     id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="10" value={string}></textarea>
      </div>

      <div className="form-group row">
        <div className="col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Parse and send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <div>
     

    </div>

  </Fragment>

);
}

return (

<Layout title="Lead Parser Input"
          description="tool for parsing leads"
          className="container col-md-8 offset-md-2">

          {formInput()}



  </Layout>
);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Also, `parseString();` is a very misleading name, because it also changes the state

Answer (score 0):

@user1953346 updating state and getting it's value right after updating won't work with hooks this way, for this you can take advantage of callbacks.

try with this, and do handle your use case with each scenario like when ck[any] is undefined.

```js
const parseString = (callback) => {
  const chunks = string.split("Select item ");
    let newLead = []
  
   for(let i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
       let ck = chunks[i].split(" "); 
       newLead.push({
        firstname: ck[1],
        lastname: ck[2],
        email: ck[5]
     })   
   }
    setLeads([...newLead])
    callback([...newLead])
}

const clickSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  parseString((updatedLeads) => console.log(updatedLeads));
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: thanks Nishant, ok it works, I know how callbacks work, but here it looks like its just logging out the updateLeads, hwo is this connected to setLeads()?

Comment: ok, I understand it, the wole expression: (updatedLeads) => console.log(updatedLeads) will be executed within parseString and the newLead-array (choise of the variable name is very bad here!!) is passed to the callback function!